# Good book for learing sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am beginner in probability theory. In order to make a better understanding of Borel Sets, Measurable Space and Random Variable, I need to learn about **algebra** and **sigma algebra**, Can anyone please suggest any good book that covers these topics for beginners **with sufficient questions (questions on algebra and sigma algebra).**

Note:
I have already seen these links [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbHZeEL98nQ&list=PLbMVogVj5nJTsl6c-UDL1luTVMT8v_RLQ), [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk4ubu7BlSk&list=PL17A1FD856FD9E1CF) and [link3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_ROD0l0hfk)

Please help me.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but any book on Measure theory (for instance, Royden's Real Analysis) should work.

Comment: Sir, I want a book that covers these topics for beginners and has sufficient questions for practice.

Comment: Try "Measures, Integrals, and Martingales" by Schilling

Comment: I think what you want is "a book on $\sigma$-algebra**s**". "Algebra and sigma algebra" doesn't make any sense, at least with singular.

Comment: see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11591/suggestions-for-a-good-measure-theory-book

Answer (score 3):

I consider Terry Tao's [Introduction to measure theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf) is a great book about measure theory and it covers the topics that you want.

You can always give it a look and judge if it is too difficult for you or not.